# The following code is not perfect no matter how it is implemented

Tags: flutter, webview, bluetooth

In flutter and webview, if you want to implement Bluetooth connection, if the connection is lost, Bluetooth scanning and connection will be performed immediately. The ultimate goal is to keep the Bluetooth connection online all the time. The following code is not perfect no matter how it is implemented, it always interrupts after scanning for a while.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import 'Tool.dart';

class AbcIndex extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AbcIndexState();
}

class _AbcIndexState extends State<AbcIndex> {
  StreamController<String> dataStreamController = StreamController<String>();
  BluetoothConnectionState connectionState = BluetoothConnectionState.disconnected;
  StreamSubscription<String>? subscription;
  late WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initBluetooth();

    // Initialize WebView
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {
          print("Page loaded: $url");

          subscription = dataStreamController.stream.listen((data) {
            // Process data received from the stream
            print('Received data from stream: $data');
            // Perform other operations, such as passing data to WebView
            String javascriptCode = 'updateData("$data")';
            // controller.runJavaScript(javascriptCode);
          }, onError: (error) {
            print('Error occurred in stream: $error');
          }, onDone: () {
            print('Stream has been closed');
          });
        },
        onWebResourceError: (error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (request) {
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ))
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.2:3000'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter Web View'),),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }

  void initBluetooth() async {
    _scanForDevices();
  }

  Future<void>  _scanForDevices() async {
    while (connectionState != BluetoothConnectionState.connected) {
      FlutterBluePlus.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));

      try {
        await for (var results in FlutterBluePlus.scanResults) {
          // Process scan results
          for (var result in results) {
            if (result.device.name.startsWith("DeviceSN")) {
              // Output device information
              print("Device name: ${result.device.name}");
              print("Device id: ${result.device.id}");

              await connectToDevice(result.device);

              FlutterBluePlus.stopScan();
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        print('Error occurred in scanResults stream: $error');
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    // Connect to the device
    await device.connect();

    // Listen to connection state changes
    device.state.listen((state) async {
      if (state == BluetoothConnectionState.connected) {
        // Connection successful, perform further operations
        print("Connected!");
        // Read device characteristics
        await readCharacteristics(device);
      } else {
        // Connection failed
        print("Bluetooth disconnected, rescanning...");
        await device.disconnect();
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
        await _scanForDevices();
      }
      setState(() {
        connectionState = state;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> readCharacteristics(BluetoothDevice device) async {

    await device.discoverServices();

    print("device.servicesList");
    for (var service in device.servicesList!) {
      if (service?.serviceUuid.toString() == "0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
        print(service);
        var characters = service?.characteristics;

        for (var character in characters!) {
          if (character.characteristicUuid.toString() == "00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
            character.setNotifyValue(true);

            String fulhex = "";
            character.value.listen((hexList) {
              String hex = CharacterToHexStr(hexList);
              dataStreamController.add(hex );
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    dataStreamController.close();
    subscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

String CharacterToHexStr(List<int> hexList) {
  String hex = '';
  for(int value in hexList) {
    String hexValue = value.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0');
    hex += hexValue;
  }
  return hex;
}
}
```

Keep your Bluetooth connection online

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken these from a few different areas, but they may help:

**Continuously Scanning**: Once you have found the device you are looking for, you should stop scanning. Continuous scanning can cause connectivity issues. In your code, you are correctly stopping the scan once the desired device is found. However, you should also include a break statement after FlutterBluePlus.stopScan(); to exit the for loop.

```
await connectToDevice(result.device);
FlutterBluePlus.stopScan();
break;
```

**Disconnect Before Reconnect**: If the connection drops, it's better to explicitly disconnect the device before trying to reconnect.

```
if (state == BluetoothConnectionState.disconnected) {
    print("Bluetooth disconnected, rescanning...");
    await device.disconnect();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    await _scanForDevices();
}
```

**Handling Exceptions**: During the Bluetooth operation, you should handle exceptions properly. For example, the connect() method can throw exceptions if the connection fails. You should wrap this method call inside a try-catch block to handle potential exceptions.

```
try {
    await device.connect();
} catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    // handle exception
}
```

**Check for Device Availability**: Make sure that the Bluetooth device is always available and within range. If the device goes out of range or turns off, the connection will be lost.

**Managing Resources**: Make sure to close any open resources when they are no longer needed. For example, you should cancel the subscription to the device state when the widget is disposed.

```
@override
void dispose() {
    dataStreamController.close();
    subscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
}
```